# How to combine FosUserBundle and HWIAothBundle login and regstration

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.3, hwioauthbundle

I am making a Login page and a Registration page
Using FosUserBundle and HWIOAuthBundle + Symfony2.4 using composer
the behaviour i would like is :
on the Login Page ->

```
        users can login using Google, Facebook or Login Through a Form
```

on the Registration Page ->

```
        users can Register using Google, Facebook or Register Through a Form
```

following this Post http://m2mdas.github.io/blog/2013/11/21/integrate-hwioauthbundle-with-fosuserbundle/

the author suggests to override the HWIOAuthBundles Login.html.twg
I override it in 
    app/Resources/HWIOAuthBundle/views/Connect
and insert the FosUserBundle Form twig code  (http://pastebin.com/8FS3Smta)
but when i try to that 
it gives errors : 
        Variable "last_username" does not exist in HWIOAuthBundle:Connect:login.html.twig at line 15

which means that HWIOauthBundle is not using/including FOSUserbundle

from what i've understood u can extend only one BaseBundle
questions:
1) is this even possible?
2) if not, what would be the correct Bundles that can proved required behaviour

any help will be greatly appreciated

--- EDIT  --- 
I was able to combine the 2 Login methods (see answer below by m2mdas)
but still cannot combine the 2 Registration methods

A workaround 
if I enter the below url it works
....app_dev.php/secure_area/connect/google
so i need to make a custom route to the URL
I have tried

```
my_registration:
    path: /secure_area/registration
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:urlRedirect
        path: /secure_area/connect/google
        permanent: true
```

but that takes me to 
....app_dev.php/secure_area/connect 
and not 
....app_dev.php/secure_area/connect/google

as intended 
TIA

Answer (score 4):

Well, I did not explain it well it seems :) I actually meant that you should copy/modify the portion

```
{% for owner in hwi_oauth_resource_owners() %}
<a href="{{ hwi_oauth_login_url(owner) }}">{{ owner | trans({}, 'HWIOAuthBundle') }}</a> <br />
{% endfor %}
```

of [HWIOAuthBundle:Connect:login.html.twig](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/views/Connect/login.html.twig) and place it to overridden [FOSUserBundle:Security:login.html.twig](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/views/Security/login.html.twig) file which `http://yoursite.com/login` displays. So the current login url would be http://yoursite.com/login instead of http://yoursite.com/connect.

But there is an additional step, in `app/config/security.yml` you have to change `login_path` option of oauth firewall to login url of FOSUserbundle which usaualy is `/login`, e.g

```
#app/config/security.yml
#....
oauth:
    #..
    login_path: /login
    #..
```

I have also [pushed a branch  in the MinimalSecurityBundlesSetup repo](https://github.com/m2mdas/MinimalSecurityBundlesSetup/tree/fos_login_integrate). You can check it as reference.

**Update: the answer regarding to registration form**

Thats where [registration_form](https://github.com/m2mdas/MinimalSecurityBundlesSetup/blob/master/app/config/config.yml#L107) config option comes to play. By default it is set to `fos_user.registration.form` which the built-in `FOSUserBundle` form. If `confirmation` option is set to true, Upon successful OAuth authentication `HWIOAuthBundle` will redirect to `http://your.site.com/connect/registration/{userid}` route in which the `FOSUserBundle` registration form is rendered.

If you have your custom registration form based on `fos_user.registration.form`([as documented in the doc](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_forms.md)) you have to set value of `registration_form` to the name of the service name of the form. Then you have to customize [HWIOAuthBundle:registration.html.twig](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/views/Connect/registration.html.twig) to match your registration page layout. Combination of normal registration page and OAuth registration page into same route seems unnecessary to me.

Comment: Thanks @m2mdas. yes i got that working too, just wasnt sure if it was the right place to include HWIAouth code.

Comment: The registration part is confusing me. 
i want users to be able to Register using 
1) Google, Facebook 
(this works at url "..../app_dev.php/secure_area/connect/")
or 
2) FosUser Registration Form. 
how to combine the above 2 registration options into a single path/route?

Comment: "Combination of normal registration page and OAuth registration page into same route seems unnecessary to me."
That is exactly wot i am trying, coz we want users without google or facebook to Login using our Form

Comment: In both pages the registration form is almost same except for OAuth related fields such as user id, etc which are optional for normal registration pages. Rendering same form in different cases is reasonable IMHO. Your requirement is certainly doable, but it will require lot of work, may even require modification of core HWIOAuthBundle code.

Comment: `fos_user.registraton.form` is now `fos_user.registration.form.type` in FOSUSerBundle v2: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/registration.xml#L16